# Ring of order $p^2$ and its characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I suppose that this question might be very easy for some people. However, I have got problem to get it. Could anyone explain to me why the characteristic of a finite ring of order $p^2$ is $p$. I know that the another characteristic is $p^2$ and it's obvious for me why but I still can not get why $p$ is also characteristic.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. The ring ${\bf Z}/p^2{\bf Z}$ has $p^2$ elements and the same characteristic.

On the other hand, any *domain* has characteristic either a prime number or zero, and if the ring is finite, its characteristic must divide the order (due to Lagrange's theorem applied to the additive group). So if a domain has order $p^2$, it must have characteristic $p$.

Incidentally, a finite ring is a domain if and only if it is a field, so the only domain of order $p^2$ is the field with $p^2$ elements.

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^p+X+1)$ have $p^p$ elements?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund: Right. My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

The ring $\mathbb Z /p^2\mathbb Z$ is a ring of characteristic $p^2$ not of characteristic $p$ as $p*1 \ne0$. The ring $\mathbb Z /p\mathbb Z \times Z /p\mathbb Z$ is a ring of order $p^2$ of characteristic $p$.